# push notification, adding functionality

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to add the push notification, so as I read, the first thing I have to do is modify my App ID, in orden to enable the push notification, the problem is the APN certificate is never generated, the screen never changes:

[image]

Needs the CSR file has some special information? I dont receive an error or a confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find this is a bug that appears in certain browsers. I had the same problem at one point. Try with Safari if you aren't already, otherwise try in another browser like Firefox or Chrome. If you have the time, submit a bug report to Apple.